# Cordova 3, Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to start my Cordova 3 application, but it seems I am running into some problems.

**Error log:**

```
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fourgamers.reader/com.fourgamers.reader.FourGamers}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:374)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:338)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:451)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at com.fourgamers.reader.FourGamers.onCreate(FourGamers.java:31)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
09-28 18:03:05.538: E/AndroidRuntime(25370):    ... 11 more
```

**FourGamers.java**

```
/*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
 */

package com.fourgamers.reader;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class FourGamers extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.fourgamers.reader" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="FourGamers" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The code you've given for FourGamers.java only has 20 lines, but the exception indicates line 31...

Comment: Sorry, I removed the default header :) Added the full one now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `CordobaActivity`, I *suspect* the problem is that you're using `loadUrl` before you've called `super.onCreate`, which means various aspects of the activity aren't hooked up yet. I suggest you switch round the lines, to this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);
```

(It's not clear why you're calling `super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl())` twice, by the way - once with a timeout and once without...)